# What Satoshi Nakomoto quotes are there in relation to forks and altcoins?

Tags: altcoin, blockchain-fork, history, satoshi-nakamoto, soft-fork

**What Satoshi Nakomoto quotes are there in relation to:**

1. **forks of Bitcoin?**
2. **forks in general?**
3. **altcoin/similar projects?**

Here I mean forks that form distinct new coins/ecosystems, not in relation to proof of work rivalry.

I think I remember a quote that had the idea that people would tend not to choose a new project over the first one, the one with sociocultural inertia. I can't seem to find it though.

I'm interested in all of Satoshi Nakomoto's quotes in relation to forks/alternative cryptocurrencies (ones that started after bitcoin genesis).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think thats too much of an open ended and broad set of multiple  questions to be answerable here but you can find the complete public writings of Satoshi Nakamoto using a search engine. I think there are several collections, some allow you to download the whole set which I found made it easier to search them. Some online collections have a built in search facility.

Some examples:

- https://satoshi.nakamotoinstitute.org/
- https://www.bitcoin.com/satoshi-archive/
- "The Book of Satoshi: The Collected Writings of Bitcoin Creator Satoshi Nakamoto" by Phil Champagne (not an endorsement, I haven't read it)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the result of my searches. Note this omits discussions on the intermittent forking natural in Proof of Work. Also, I alas didn't find the quote I had in mind in the question.

### 1. Forks of Bitcoin

**SHA256 breaking**

[`Bitcoin Forum: Re: Dealing with SHA-256 Collisions June 14, 2010, 08:39:50 PM`](https://www.bitcoin.com/satoshi-archive/forum/bitcoin-forum/115/#selection-25.0-25.62)

> If SHA-256 became completely broken, I think we could come to some
> agreement about what the honest block chain was before the trouble
> started, lock that in and continue from there with a new hash
> function.
>
> If the hash breakdown came gradually, we could transition to a new
> hash in an orderly way.  The software would be programmed to start
> using a new hash after a certain block number.  Everyone would have to
> upgrade by that time.  The software could save the new hash of all the
> old blocks to make sure a different block with the same old hash can't
> be used.

see also [`Re: Hash() function not secure July 16, 2010, 04:13:53 PM`](https://www.bitcoin.com/satoshi-archive/forum/bitcoin-forum/212/#selection-25.0-25.57)

**Internet segmentation**

[`Bitcoin Forum: Re: Anonymity July 08, 2010, 07:12:00 PM`](https://www.bitcoin.com/satoshi-archive/forum/bitcoin-forum/168/#selection-25.0-25.41)

> ...
> Any node with access to both sides would automatically flow the
> block chain over, such as someone getting around the blockade with a
> dial-up modem or sat-phone.  It would only take one node to do it.
> Anyone who wants to keep doing business would be motivated.
> ...

**Signature compromise**

[`Bitcoin Forum: Re: Major Meltdown July 10, 2010, 01:36:17 PM`](https://www.bitcoin.com/satoshi-archive/forum/bitcoin-forum/173/#selection-25.0-25.45)

> Quote from "llama" > However, if something happened and the signatures were compromised (perhaps integer factorization is solved, quantum
> computers?), then even agreeing upon the last valid block would be
> worthless.

> True, if it happened suddenly.  If it happens gradually, we can still
> transition to something stronger.  When you run the upgraded software
> for the first time, it would re-sign all your money with the new
> stronger signature algorithm.  (by creating a transaction sending the
> money to yourself with the stronger sig)

**Longest chain**

[`re. Hal Finney Bitcoin P2P e-cash paper - 2008-11-09 01:58:48 UTC`](https://www.bitcoin.com/satoshi-archive/emails/cryptography/6/#selection-29.3312-29.3440)

> ... The only way for everyone to stay on the same page is to believe that
> the longest chain is always the valid one, no matter what.

### 2. Forks in general

I didn't find anything.

### 3. Altcoin/similar projects

**BitDNS**

[`re. Mike Hearn <mike@plan99.net> Wed, Mar 9, 2011 at 7:39 PM`](https://www.bitcoin.com/satoshi-archive/forum/bitcoin-forum/115/#selection-25.0-25.62)

> Procedure to hash a BitDNS block:
>
> - hash the BitDNS block
> - construct a Bitcoin block
> - insert the BitDNS hash into the scriptSig of tx 0 in the Bitcoin block
> - hash the Bitcoin block   The BitDNS block is valid if that hash is below BitDNS's target.

(quote truncated, see [source](https://www.bitcoin.com/satoshi-archive/emails/mike-hearn/14/#selection-25.3722-25.3976))

**Ripple**

[`p2presearch@listcultures.org Fri, 13 Feb 2009 02:31`](https://www.bitcoin.com/satoshi-archive/emails/p2p-research/4/)

> > Are you familiar with Ripple?
>
> As trust systems go, Ripple is unique in spreading trust around rather
> than concentrating it.